# How do I add a meta pixel event upon successful completion of a Ninja Forms (Free Version) form in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-pixel, ninja-forms, facebook-analytics

On my service based business Wordpress website, I receive inquiries from customers. There is a Name, Email, and Message field. It has the default settings for the Ninja Forms Free version plugin. I embedded the Facebook Pixel using the PixelMySite plugin. The end goal is to be able to give the Facebook algorithm what it needs to successfully advertise with a goal of conversions. In this case, the successful submission of the form from a human being.

What would be the best way to implement a solution where the pixel sends a "lead" event when the form is submitted?

I tried creating a lead event for when the submit button is pressed using the Event Setup Tool but that does not really prevent spamming so it doesn't seem ideal. I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: What action happens when the form is submitted? Does it redirect to a specific page or is in using AJAX to confirm submission?